# DHCP client bind error on port 68

Tags: dhcp

I am creating a dhcp client in Linux(Ubuntu). I am creating a udp socket and binding it to port 68 and then call recvfrom. I receive a permission denied bind error. I suspect there is a daemon or process which is already bound to port 68. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be super user to bind to ports lower than 1024, have you tried running it with **sudo**?

To find out if something is bound to port 68, do:

> `sudo netstat -l -u -n -p | grep 68`

Comment: i thought you connect to server at port 67 and bind the socket to port 68

Answer (score 1):

Question: Are you root?  You must be root to bind to a [privileged port](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) (less that 1024).

Answer (score 1):

netstat is your guy for finding all your network connections.

you want something like netstat -l, to display listening endpoints.